# EF: OrderBy is not working when I define a delegate with the same signature

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I've replaced a SqlDataSource with a ObjectDataSource. Here's a portion of my Select Method

```
Func<User, string> sortByDlg = (u) =>
{
  string sortStr = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) ? "UserName" : sortColumn;
  return sortStr;
};

var users = db.Users.OrderBy(sortByDlg).ToList();
```

The first time the page loads, I want rows to be sorted by **UserName**, after that by the column selected.

When I run the code, no sorting is happening. It works only when I put back the anonymous method: `OrderBy(u => u.UserName)`.

Here's the complete method

```
public static List<UserViewModel> GetAllUserViewModels(string sortColumn)
{
  using (var db = myDbContext.Create())
  {
    var model = new List<UserViewModel>();
    Func<User, string> sortByDlg = (u) =>
    {
        string sortStr = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) ? "UserName" : sortColumn;
          return sortStr;
    };

    var users = db.Users.OrderBy(sortByDlg).ToList();
    foreach (var item in users)
    {
        var u = new UserViewModel
        {
           UserID = item.Id,
           First_Name = item.FirstName,
           Last_Name = item.LastName,
           telephone = item.Telephone,
           //more here ...
         };

         model.Add(u);
       }
       return model;
     }
    }
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Yes. It's passing for each item being returned.

Comment: It is Ordering by the constant "UserName" -- for each row (not the value in column UserName).  Just like this would: `.OrderBy(u=> "UserName")`

Comment: Just to add to the comment by @RobertMcKee, your delegate needs to return the value to be sorted not the name of a column.  You could extend this delegate to return the value of a named property using reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it, because I find it simple to understand (without using expression trees):

```
public static List<UserViewModel> GetAllUserViewModels(string sortColumn)
{
  using (var db = myDbContext.Create())
  {
    var query = db.Users.AsQueryable();
    switch(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) ? "UserName" : sortColumn)
    {
       case "UserName": query=query.OrderBy(u=>u.UserName); break;
       case "FirstName": query=query.OrderBy(u=>u.FirstName); break;
       ... more ...
    }
    var model = query.Select(u=> new UserViewModel {
           UserID = item.Id,
           First_Name = item.FirstName,
           Last_Name = item.LastName,
           telephone = item.Telephone,
           //more here ...
         }).ToList();
    return model;
  }
}
```

Actually, I would create functions for GetAllUsers that returns `IQueryable<User>`, a separate extension method `IQueryable<User> OrderByColumn(this IQueryable<User> u,string sortColumn)`, and another extension `IEnumerable<UserViewModelItem> ToViewModel(this IQueryable<User> u)`, and use them like: `var result = GetAllUsers().OrderByColumn("UserName").ToViewModel();`

```
// db defined elsewhere (repository pattern?)    
public IQueryable<User> GetAllUsers()
{
    return db.Users.AsQueryable();
}

public static IQueryable<User> OrderByColumn(this IQueryable<User> u,string sortColumn)
{
    switch(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) ? "UserName" : sortColumn)
    {
       case "UserName": return u.OrderBy(u=>u.UserName); break;
       case "FirstName": return u.OrderBy(u=>u.FirstName); break;
       ... more ...
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<UserViewModelItem> ToViewModel(this IQueryable<User> users)
{
    return users.Select(u=> new UserViewModelItem {
           UserID = item.Id,
           First_Name = item.FirstName,
           Last_Name = item.LastName,
           telephone = item.Telephone,
           //more here ...
         }).ToList();
}
```